# Differentiating circumferential and non-circumferential faces

Tags: geometry, surfaces

Let's imagine a ring sector (from a random planar face revolved 360deg). Is there a way to differentiate between the non-circumferential faces and the circumferential faces ? The available information are the centers of gravity, surfaces areas, volume centroid of the ring, a point on each surface and normals.

[image: Example]

For instance, in the image above I would like to differentiate between the blue faces and the white ones. Please note that this ring has been made from a square face revolved but the geometry could come from any type of cross section. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Is the normal associated with the point on the surface? If so, then the point + normal pair for each face defines a tangential plane. The tangential planes for the blue faces would intersect in the axis of revolution, and all the other normal lines (i.e. lines spanned by normal vectors starting at point on the face) would intersect that axis.

Comment: Yes the normal is associated to the point on the surface. However I cannot really visualise your logic. Could you please develop a bit further the idea or draw something? Many thanks.